# Uniformly continuous integrable function f

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be uniformly continuous such that $\int_1^\infty{f}$ converges. It's known that implies $f(x) = o(1) $ as x tends to infinity. Altrough I'd like to show that $f(x) = o(\frac{1}{x})$ which is much harder. Can you give me a hint? Or, maybe, you have a counterexample?

I have a great counter example now which is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really neat and great counterexample is $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. I suppose it helps better to understand why the given statement is false rather than mathcounterexamples.net answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $I=[-\frac{\pi}{2} \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
\cos x & x \in I\\
0 & x \notin I
\end{cases}$$

$g$ is continuous.

Now $$f(x)= \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \frac{g(n^2x-n^4)}{n^2}$$ is a counterexample.

Comment: But is this function f uniformly continuous?

Comment: It is $1$ Lipschitz.

Comment: That function is not a counter example to my question then.

Comment: For sure it is as a $1$-Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous!

Comment: Can you please explain why it's integrable and 1-Lipschitz or where to read about this function?

Comment: I suggest that you study the maps  $x \mapsto \frac{g(n^2x-n^4)}{n^2}$ and their derivatives to understand why $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ is finite and why $f$ is uniformly continuous.